# Combining two REGEX in Python for compiling

Tags: python, regex, compilation

I'm using REGEX to compile a list of strings from an HTML document in Python.
The strings are either found inside a td tag (`<td>SOME OF THE STRINGS COULD BE HERE</td>`) or inside a div tag (`<div style="line-height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;">SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE</div>`).

Since the order of the strings inside the final list should correspond to the order in which they appear inside the HTML document, I am looking for a REGEX that will allow me to compile all of these strings considering both possible cases.

I know how to do it individually with something that looks like:

```
FindStrings = re.compile('(?<=\<td>)(.*?)(?=\</td>)')
MyList = re.findall(FindStrings, str(mydocument))
```

for the first case, but would like to know the most efficient way to combine both cases inside a unique REGEX.

Comment: Why don't you use beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine regex pattern by using regex OR. Btw, you don't need to use regex lookarounds.

You can use this regex:

```
<td>(.+?)</td>|<div.*?>(.+?)</div>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/2)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-37]  `SOME OF THE STRINGS COULD BE HERE`
MATCH 2
2.  [94-125]    `SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE`
QUICK REFERENCE
```

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """<td>SOME OF THE STRINGS COULD BE HERE</td>
... <div style="line-height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;">SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE</div>
... """
>>> m = re.findall(r'<td>(.+?)</td>|<div.*?>(.+?)</div>', s)
>>> m
[('SOME OF THE STRINGS COULD BE HERE', ''), ('', 'SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE')]
>>> [s for s in x if s for x in m]
['SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE', 'SOME STRINGS COULD ALSO BE HERE']
```

Comment: Seems to do half of the job done... I get a list of multiple strings couple, including an empty one. [('', 'One of the string'), ('', 'Another one'), ...]

Comment: Hi @LaGuille as you can see in the screenshot it takes both needed strings

Answer (score 0):

```
<td[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/td>).)*)<\/td>|<div[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/div>).)*)<\/div>
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/mD7gK4/11